# Initialize my std::map

Tags: c++, stl, initialization

I have written the below code which uses a `Map`.  This program finds the number of times the `string` key appears in the `Map`.  If it appears only once, then the value of `int` for that `string` key should be 1, and so on.  This program runs and produces the required output - but I feel that it is pure luck, because I am not *initializing* the *Map* anywhere.  I am just doing `myMap[str]++` - this in no way guarantees that initially the value was `0`.  So, how do I initialize the map so that the value for any `string` key is `0`, before it is encountered and I do a `myMap[str]++`?

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<map>

int main()
{
    int t;
    long int n;
    std::string str;
    std::map< std::string, int > myMap;
    scanf("%d", &t);

    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%ld", &n);
        std::cin.ignore();
        while(n--)
        {
            getline(std::cin, str);
            myMap[str]++;
        }

        for(std::map< std::string, int >::iterator it=myMap.begin(); it!=myMap.end(); it++)
            printf("%s %d\n", it->first.c_str(), it->second);
        printf("\n");

        myMap.erase(myMap.begin(), myMap.end());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample input:

> 2 
>   6 
>   03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142 
>   03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141 
>   30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141 
>   30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142 
>   30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141 
>   30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142 
>   
>   5 
>   30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0144 
>   30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142 
>   30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0145 
>   30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0146 
>   30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0143

Sample output:

> 03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141 1 
>   03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142 1 
>   30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141 2 
>   30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142 2 
>   
>   30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142 1 
>   30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0143 1 
>   30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0144 1 
>   30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0145 1 
>   30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0146 1

Detailed problem description can be found [here](http://www.spoj.com/problems/SBANK/).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said:

> this in no way guarantees that initially the value was 0

That is not correct. When an item corresponding to a key is not there in a map, it is value initialized when you use the `operator[]` function.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at:

> If an insertion is performed, the mapped value is value-initialized (default-constructed for class types, zero-initialized otherwise) and a reference to it is returned.

In other words,

```
        myMap[str]++;
```

is valid and correct code.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the key is already existing using `std::map::find()`. If it exists, you do the increment on the item pointed to by the iterator returned from find. Else, you write `myMap[str] = 0`.

```
   while(n--)
   {
        getline(std::cin, str);
        std::map< std::string, int >::iterator it = myMap.find(str);
        if( myMap.end() != it )
             (*it).second++;
        else
            myMap[str] = 1;
   }
```

Nevertheless, your code is okay as the the int is initialized in your code. It is just not visible (the `std::pair<string,int>` is being default-constructed).

Comment: Sorry, this was not my question.  My question was - why does `++` increment the value to `1` because I haven't initialized it to `0`?  Answer, as R. Sahu pointed out is, primitive datatypes are *zero-initialized* in map.  Thanks though. :)

Comment: @CodingBatman And there I thought your question was "So, how do I initialize the map so that the value for any string key is 0, before it is encountered..."